# How to check the data type of the properties of an object?

Tags: powershell

The following code

```
$str = '{"attrs": { "c1": "abc", "c2": 123}}'
$json = $str | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.attrs | Get-Member -MemberType Properties | % { echo $_.GetType() }
```

returns

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    MemberDefinition                         System.Object
True     False    MemberDefinition                         System.Object
```

Why it doesn't tell if the properties have the data type of `string` or `int`?

I want to tell if the property has the data type of string. So I can wrap the str values with `"` when creating a CSV string.

```
($json.attrs 
 | Get-Member -MemberType Properties 
 | % { if (it's str) { return "`"$_`"" } else { $_ }
) -join ','
```

Comment: Why would you do such a thing, why manually build a CSV string when `Export-Csv` can do that for you?

Comment: I will need to construct `$json` at run time. Hmm, maybe I can save the converted objects in a big array in memory and then call `export-csv`.

Comment: not necessarily, if you stream your logic and pipe it to `| Export-Csv ...` it will not need to be all in memory

Comment: I think Powershell doesn't have Generator (yield)?

Comment: `$json.attrs | Export-Csv path\to\csv.csv -NoTypeInformation` give that a try

Comment: The `$str` in my question will actually have a list `[{...}, {...},...]`. And for each item in the list, it will generate 1 to many items depends on the value. So it will be `$jsons | % { process-item $_ } # process-item generate one or more items`. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question as asked:

Use the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject) to reflect on a given object's properties:

```bash
$json.attrs.psobject.Properties.Value | ForEach-Object GetType
```

To *test* a given property for being of a specific type:

```bash
$propName = 'c1'
$json.attrs.$propName -is [string] # -> $true
```

---

However, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out:

For exporting the parsed-from-JSON data *to CSV*, *you don't need to know the data type* of the properties, given that (a) CSV is invariably an *untyped*, *text-only* format and (b) PowerShell's [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) cmdlet *by default* encloses field values in `"..."`.